# getting error when opening the generated pdf file from xsl-fo

Tags: java, pdf, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

This is XML file

```
<projectteam>
    <projectname>The Killer Application</projectname>
    <member>
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <function>lead</function>
        <email>jon.doe@killerapp.fun</email>
    </member>
    <member>
        <name>Paul Coder</name>
        <function>dev</function>
        <email>paul.coder@killerapp.fun</email>
    </member>
    <member>
        <name>Max Hacker</name>
        <function>dev</function>
        <email>max.hacker@killerapp.fun</email>
    </member>
    <member>
        <name>Donna Book</name>
        <function>doc</function>
        <email>donna.book@killerapp.fun</email>
    </member>
    <member>
        <name>Henry Tester</name>
        <function>qa</function>
        <email>henry.tester@killerapp.fun</email>
    </member>
</projectteam>
```

This is XSL file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- $Id$ -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:param name="versionParam" select="'1.0'" />
    <!-- ========================= -->
    <!-- root element: projectteam -->
    <!-- ========================= -->
    <xsl:template match="projectteam">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4"
                    page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="2cm"
                    margin-bottom="2cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-right="2cm">
                    <fo:region-body />
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simpleA4">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block font-size="16pt" font-weight="bold" space-after="5mm">
                        Project:
                        <xsl:value-of select="projectname" />
                    </fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="12pt" space-after="5mm">
                        Version
                        <xsl:value-of select="$versionParam" />
                    </fo:block>
                    <fo:block font-size="10pt">
                        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"
                            border-collapse="separate">
                            <fo:table-column column-width="4cm" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="4cm" />
                            <fo:table-column column-width="5cm" />
                            <fo:table-body>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="member" />
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </fo:table>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- ========================= -->
    <!-- child element: member     -->
    <!-- ========================= -->
    <xsl:template match="member">
        <fo:table-row>
            <xsl:if test="function = 'lead'">
                <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="function" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="email" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have added these file to my code

```
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 * contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 * this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 * The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 * (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

/* $Id: ExampleXML2PDF.java 1356646 2012-07-03 09:46:41Z mehdi $ */

package embedding;

//Java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent;
import org.apache.fop.apps.Fop;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory;
import org.apache.fop.apps.MimeConstants;

/**
 * This class demonstrates the conversion of an XML file to PDF using
 * JAXP (XSLT) and FOP (XSL-FO).
 */
public class ExampleXML2PDF {

    /**
     * Main method.
     * @param args command-line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("FOP ExampleXML2PDF\n");
            System.out.println("Preparing...");

            // Setup directories
            File baseDir = new File(".");
            File outDir = new File(baseDir, "out");
            outDir.mkdirs();

            // Setup input and output files
            File xmlfile = new File(baseDir, "xml/xml/projectteam.xml");
            File xsltfile = new File(baseDir, "xml/xslt/projectteam2fo.xsl");
            File pdffile = new File(outDir, "ResultXML2PDF.pdf");

            System.out.println("Input: XML (" + xmlfile + ")");
            System.out.println("Stylesheet: " + xsltfile);
            System.out.println("Output: PDF (" + pdffile + ")");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Transforming...");

            // configure fopFactory as desired
            final FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(".").toURI());

            FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
            // configure foUserAgent as desired

            // Setup output
            OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(pdffile);
            out = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(out);

            try {
                // Construct fop with desired output format
                Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);

                // Setup XSLT
                TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltfile));

                // Set the value of a <param> in the stylesheet
                transformer.setParameter("versionParam", "2.0");

                // Setup input for XSLT transformation
                Source src = new StreamSource(xmlfile);

                // Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through to FOP
                Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

                // Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
                transformer.transform(src, res);
            } finally {
                out.close();
            }

            System.out.println("Success!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

when i am running this code it is saying successful but when i am opening the pdf i am getting "Adobe Reader could not open the file 'pdffile.pdf' because it is etiher not a supported file or because the file has been  damaged". how to resolve this ,do i wrong anywhere.
this only i have done but not able to read pdf.

Comment: What's the resulting PDF-file looking like if you open it by a text editor?

Comment: It's giving error Adobe reader could not open the PDF because it's not supported or file has been damaged

Comment: I know about that error message, you mentioned it already. But I asked what the file looks like in a text editor e.g. like Notepad.

Comment: What platform are you on? Which versions of the involved libraries? I tried your code on CentOS 6 and I get a valid PDF file which can be opened with the Adobe PDF reader.

Comment: its looking like in notepad++ pdf 1.4 kJIMH i am on java platform and windows.

Comment: Tried again on Windows 7, using Java 1.8 and Apache FOP 2.2. I still get a valid PDF as output which can be opened with the Adobe PDF reader.

Comment: is there problem with pdf version which version u have for pdf?

Comment: The PDF version of the generated PDF is 1.4, the version of the Acrobat Reader is 2017.012.20098.

Comment: Have you checked the resulting PDF **file size**? If for some reason the file is created but nothing is written to it, its size is 0KB and Acrobat gives that error message about it being not supported or corrupted (which in this case is quite misleading).

Comment: for that reason what should i do?

Comment: PDF is not of 0 size.